# Вертикальный слеш в адресной строке Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Изменяю адресную строку через js, упрощенный пример:

```
history.pushState("",document.title,location.origin+"/a|b|c");
```

Есть проблема в Chrome - вертикальный слеш заменяется на %7C, как это решить?

Comment: А где проблема?

Comment: @AlexeyTen, в том, что в адресной строке хрома выводится не a|b|c, а a%7Cb%7Cc.

Comment: Полагаю, это проблема самого браузера, если просто ввести в строку |, то она тоже заменится кодом.

Comment: Это не проблема, он обязан всегда заменяться по стандарту [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986). Если он перестанет заменяться — тогда это будет проблемой

Comment: @andreymal в firefox выводится, как есть. Ну, ладно, раз такое дело, будем искать другие варианты.

Comment: А впрочем, оказывается, есть [другой стандарт](https://url.spec.whatwg.org), согласно которому он заменяться НЕ должен. Так что настоящая проблема на самом деле в том, что разработчики браузеров не могут определиться, надо заменять или не надо)

Comment: @andreymal на самом деле ни тот, ни другой стандарт не описывают что браузер должен **показывать в адресной строке**. Safari там вообще только домен показывает…

Comment: Если вам просто нужен разделитель, то посмотрите на `*` или `!`.

Comment: @AlexeyTen спасибо, но ни то, ни то не подходит.